# HTML table Export to Excel using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I'm trying html table to export excel using angularJS. I'm able to achieve this. But when i exporting to excel i want to remove some tr and td's. How to achieve this task. Thanks in advance
Below is my angular code

```
angular.module('xxxApp').factory('Excel',function($window){
        var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('MyExcelCtrl',function(Excel,$timeout,$scope){
      $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
            var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'AdminUsers');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = exportHref;
            a.download = 'Admin_Users.xls';
            a.click();
        }
      $scope.isExportToExcel= false;

    });
```

Kindly help me on this

Comment: Do you have any option to export JSON instead export the html table? I guess you have a json array which in turn being rendered as html table

Comment: I don't have control on JSON which is turning rendered as html. I need to play with html table only.

Comment: One more issue i am facing now. I'm not able to download the exported excel in IE and FireFox browser But it'e working fine in Chrome browser. Anything i need to add to my code for browser comparability?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this working  and example1 is the id on putting in HTML table element**

```
  $scope.exportData = function () {

        debugger;
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{CouponDetails}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

        var table = document.getElementById("example1");
         var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML };
        var url = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'Expoerdata.xls';
        a.click();
    };
```